# indexing with solr

Tags: solr, field

I'm using solrj to index data, I have created some new field in schema.xml, when I try to index data by java I have to use all new fields, if I don't use one of this new field I have an exception  org.apache.solr.common.solrexception bad request
Can I index Data with fields that I choose?

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: what two fields? please post all relevant information.

Comment: ok, in schema.xml I have added this tow fields
<field name="t1" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" /> 
<field name="t2" type="FrenchAna" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
and in my java code I wrote 
 SolrInputDocument doc2 = new SolrInputDocument();
 doc2.addField("t1", "test1", 1.0f);
 doc2.addField("t2", "test2", 1.0f);
this code index my Data, but the probleme when I don't use the field t1 or t2 example: 
 SolrInputDocument doc2 = new SolrInputDocument();
 doc2.addField("t1", "test1", 1.0f);
 //doc2.addField("t2", "test2", 1.0f); 

I get the exception

Comment: Please post that in the question, not in comments, so it can be properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all of your defined fields in schema.xml has set the attribute "required" as "true".
Set the attribute to false and the field is not longer necessary for each document.